# how to parse the value to integer in <ui:repeat value="..." var="...">?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have a code like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myController.fileList}}"  var="element" >
<t:inputFileUpload value="#{myController.uploadedFile[element]}"  />
</ui:repeat>
```

but this returns an error : java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[0]}". UploadedFile is an array of Files. When i wrote code like this

```
...
<t:inputFileUpload value="#{myController.uploadedFile[0]}"  />
...
```

everything is ok, but i want to have there values between 0-8, not only '0', and this has to be returned from my controller. So how to convert this 'element' to int value inside `<t:inputFileUpload value="#{myController.uploadedFile[element]}"  />`? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can use the [`varStatus` attribute](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) to obtain the loop status.</strike>

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myController.fileList}" var="element" varStatus="loop">
    <t:inputFileUpload value="#{myController.uploadedFile[loop.index]}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

*(only available in JSF 2.x by the way, in JSF 1.x your best bet might be `c:forEach`)*

But why don't you just use the following?

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myController.uploadedFile}" var="uploadedFile">
    <t:inputFileUpload value="#{uploadedFile}" />
</ui:repeat>
```

---

**Update**: the `fileList` must be of type `List<Integer>` or `Integer[]` or `int[]` and the `uploadedFile` must be of type `List<SomeObject>` or `SomeObject[]` to get your initial code to work.

---

**Update 2**: here's a small reproducible test snippet:

XHTML:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{bean.selectedIndexes}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectIndexes}" />
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    <h:commandButton value="submit" />
</h:form>
<ui:repeat value="#{bean.selectedIndexes}" var="selectedIndex">
    <p><h:outputText value="#{bean.list[selectedIndex]}" /></p>
</ui:repeat>
```

`Bean`:

```
private List<SelectItem> selectIndexes; // +getter
private List<Integer> selectedIndexes; // +getter +setter
private List<String> list; // +getter

public Bean() {
    selectIndexes = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    selectIndexes.add(new SelectItem(0, "one"));
    selectIndexes.add(new SelectItem(1, "two"));
    selectIndexes.add(new SelectItem(2, "three"));
    selectIndexes.add(new SelectItem(3, "four"));
    selectedIndexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four");
}
```

Works fine here on Mojarra 2.0.3 and Apache Tomcat 6.0.29. You only need to substitute `selectedIndexes` as `fileList` and `list` as `uploadedFile`.

Comment: I can`t use the first solution. The reason is: user is selecting files that should be modified by him. There are 0-8 files. The names of the files are also 0-8. If he choose only second and fourth file i want to show him only two <t:inputFile> elements - he can overwrite only this two files which he has selected previously. In this case i want know which files should be replaced. If he select all eight files your solutions could work. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The `fileList` contains the selected files for which you'd like to use the related `uploadedFile`. OK, I updated the answer.

Comment: I wrote something like this in my controller: List<Integer> result = new LinkedList<Integer>(); and i`m returning this list. i thought firstly that it will work but error is still appears.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce your problem. See answer update for a small test snippet.

Comment: You won`t believe - my previous code worked but i had stupid mistake on my xhtml page - value="#{myController.fileList}}" - i used there double brackets '}}' so server couldn`t convert it to int and treated it like String. Sorry for a problem and thanks for your replies. Your advices were helpfull like always :). Regards.